# How to filter multiple domains in Firefox DevTools' Network panel?

Tags: firefox, firefox-developer-tools

I am debugging an API request in Firefox and I am looking to filter multiple domains in the developer tools' Network panel. I can filter by one domain with the `domain:domainname.com`, but how do I add additional domains?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Filtering by two domains is not directly possible because the filters in the **Network** panel is always accumulative, though one workaround is to use a [regular expression property filter](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/devtools-user/network_monitor/request_list/index.html#filtering-by-properties).

This allows you to provide several domains separating them by pipes (`|`) like this:

```
regexp:domain1.com|domain2.com
```

That should work in most cases, but note that this is not just filtering by domain but searching within all the data inside the requests. That means that when the domain name appears in one of the other columns, the request will also be listed.

Another way to achieve this is to use **negative filtering** by prepending the filter expression with a minus (`-`).

So in order to get the requests of two domains you have to write several `-domain:` expressions for all domains you want to *exclude*.

Comment: thanks so much, I also found another useful tool to monitor all outgoing network requests https://www.telerik.com/fiddler

Comment: The bug request seems outdated as `regexp:` is currently implemented. See other answer.

Comment: @JoséAndias You're right. The feature request I had linked referred to the search side panel within the Network panel and was unrelated to filtering. Filtering by regular expressions is already available since Firefox 55 (see https://bugzil.la/1354495). I've changed my answer in order to provide that information. Thank you!

Comment: I'm glad that this works, but who's "bright" idea was it to make all other filters simply use regex by encapsulating it in / and HERE it has to be done with a keyword?...

Answer (score 5):

There's also the `regexp` keyword to use Regular Expressions for URL filtering.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor/request_list#Filtering_by_properties

Answer (score 5):

If you want to filter *out* domains that are cluttering up your requests pane, you simply use the `-` prefix and separate them with spaces.

`-domain:domain.com -domain:domain2.com`

The important thing here is that in Firefox you cannot use wildcards like you can in Chrome. So this won't work.

`-domain:email.*.com`

This is what kept tripping me up. Also, for awhile I thought you separated them with commas. Nope, use spaces.